# How to update column values starting with zero in MapInfo Pro

Tags: mapinfo, update, column, leading-zero

When I choose the Update Column function in MapInfo Pro 12.5, if I type in rowid*50 it will make intervals of 50 which is all fine, but how do I get the first column to be zero and then update the rest ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Help people to help you Nikki, what software are you using?

Comment: I am using map info  professional 12.5

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure to understand your intention but here is some suggestions :

| State name | Intervals of 50 (v1) | Intervals of 50 (v2) | Intervals of 50 (v3) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 50 | 0 | 0 |
| BB | 100 | 100 | 50 |
| CC | 150 | 150 | 100 |
| DD | 200 | 200 | 150 |
| EE | 250 | 250 | 200 |

To get Intervals of 50 (v1), you can use `rowid*50` as you mentionned.

To get Intervals of 50 (v2), you can put this as an expression :

```
If rowid=1 Then 
    0
Else 
    rowid*50
End If
```

To get Intervals of 50 (v3), you can use `(rowid-1)*50` as a value.

**Note** : You can get to the *Expression* window by clicking on *Assist* right to the *Value* box.

Comment: Thank you so much that solved my problem :-)

Comment: You don't need an `If`-`Then`-`Else` for `(rowid-1)*50` (v3)

Comment: That's awkward, thank you @Vince. I edited my post.